# Create a tooltip for each dot on a scatter plot created for a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas based scatter plot that is created from a dataframe, with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.formula.api as smapi
import numpy as np


data = pd.read_csv('new.csv', sep=";", decimal=".")

%matplotlib inline
sns.set() 
data.plot(kind="scatter", x="BestValue", y="WorseValue")
```

I would like an easy way to identify each "dot" on the plot. For example, a tooltip when the mouse is over. The value of the tooltip would be another "column" of the dataframe `data`.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use plotly library instead of seaborn to get tooltips on the graphs, these tooltips will be customizable based on requirement.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import statsmodels.formula.api as smapi
import numpy as np


data = pd.read_csv('new.csv', sep=";", decimal=".")

fig = px.scatter(data, x="BestValue", y="WorseValue")
fig.show()
```

If it is required to be done in matplotlib, refer to a question already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908636/how-to-add-hovering-annotations-in-matplotlib